# SAS MP (Multi Processing) Connect

Tags: sas

I am developing my first piece of code using SAS MP Connect to run parallel threads from the same sas job.

I understand that MP CONNECT is limited physically only by the number of CPUs available, but I ideally don't want to be using all of them for my job!

Does SAS have an option to limit the number of MP CONNECT processes that are executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on MP Connect, but even in BASE SAS, you have OPTION CPUCOUNT available, whereby you can set the number of CPUs SAS has available to it.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002197020.htm

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any `MP CONNECT` limitations related to the number of CPUs available.  `MP CONNECT` is just a technique to create multiple SAS sessions that execute at the same time, all under the control of a "parent" session.  The bigger concerns are I/O and memory, since each session is it's own process.  You can even run `MP CONNECT` processes on a single CPU machine (in which case you'd not get true parallel performance of course).

Also, to your specific question, there is not an option to control how many `MP CONNECT` sessions you can invoke.

Here is a [pretty good SAS paper](http://support.sas.com/rnd/scalability/papers/mpconnect0401.pdf); although it's a bit old, the principles are still valid.